# Alternate of Popup Window (Same functionality)

Tags: c#, web, popupwindow

I am working on a website (C#, .Net 3.5 Framework) and looking for an alternate of `Popup window` to avoid the popup blocker settings of browsers or in other words want to remove the dependency of popup blocker for Website. Many users disable them because they don't like it.

I am using Master page for Menus and common interface of website.

But all the requirements are same.

1. Overlapped window
2. `Common Interface/component` that can be used to display the content of other HTML/ASPX page
3. Value can be `passed and returned` to the Opener Window.

Which is the best option for this scenario?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way, as an alternate of popup window.

**Style Sheet** (Popup related CSS)
Purpose: CSS for popup window

```
.PopupOuterDiv
{
height:100%;
width:100%;
top:0px;
left:0px;
background-color:#000000;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity:.50;
opacity:.50;
z-index:50;
}

.PopupInnerDiv
{
position:fixed;
background-color:#ffffff;
z-index:50;
left:25%;
right:25%;
top:25%;
border-right: #0066ff 5px solid;
border-top: #0066ff 5px solid;
border-left: #0066ff 5px solid;
border-bottom: #0066ff 5px solid;
font-family: Arial;
}

.PopoupTitle
{
background-color: #0066ff;
height:25px;
color: white;
}

.PopoupButton
{
color: #ffffff;
width:20px;
border:white 1px solid;
background-color: #663300;
}
```

**Master Page** 

Purpose: Contains the Common code for popup
1. Create 1 Div for Outer faded Effect
2. Create Div as container or popup Window
3. Create Iframe inside a container DIV and assign the URL.

```
 <div class="PopupOuterDiv" runat="server" id="PopupOuterDiv" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div class="PopupInnerDiv" runat="server" id="PopupInnerDiv" style="display:none;">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr class="PopoupTitle">
            <td id="PopoupTitle"></td>
            <td align="right">
                <input class="PopoupButton" type="Button" value="X" onclick="closePopup();" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:8px;" ><td></td></tr>        
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;
            <iframe id="PopupIframe" src="" runat="server" height="300px" width="480px"></iframe> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript** to open and close the Popup

```
   function closePopup()
  {
    document.getElementById('<%=PopupOuterDiv.ClientID%>').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('<%=PopupInnerDiv.ClientID%>').style.display = 'none';
  }

  function openPopup(PopupTitle, PopupURL)
  {
    document.getElementById('<%=PopupOuterDiv.ClientID%>').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('<%=PopupInnerDiv.ClientID%>').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('PopoupTitle').innerText = PopupTitle;    
    document.getElementById('<%=PopupIframe.ClientID%>').src = PopupURL;    
  }
```

**Content Page**

Call the popup window from any content page.

```
openPopup('My Custom Popup', '../aspx/User.aspx');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is javascript, maybe modal plugin of jquery, but... The problem is, that it isn't 100% reliable as well. Many people disable javascript or maybe don't have a browser with that js (some older mobile phones etc.).